# Data Tidying and Creating Timeline in R

Tags: r

I am having trouble to plot my data in a timeline. I have 3 columns of data. First column is the date. Second column is either "+" or "-". ("+" indicates start date, "-" indicates end date for timeline) And finally the third column is the name of event. FYI.This data is incredibly long.

I guess first step is to create a 4th column for rows with "+" and fill it with the "date" columns of the rows with "-". Then delete the rows with "-". Then i can simply use timevis() command. But i couldn't reshape the data. Becase for example for event A, there are several "+" and "-". I couldnt manage to copy the date of a "-" row to the previous A"+".

```
date     status name
01.01.2001  +   A
02.01.2001  +   B
02.01.2001  +   C
03.01.2001  -   B
04.01.2001  +   B
07.01.2001  -   A
09.01.2001  -   C
11.01.2001  +   A
13.01.2001  -   B
```

Is there a way to plot a timeline without having start and end dates on the same row? or how can i format the data like below;

```
date     status name  enddate
01.01.2001  +   A   07.01.2001
02.01.2001  +   B   03.01.2001
02.01.2001  +   C   09.01.2001
04.01.2001  +   B   13.01.2001
11.01.2001  +   A   NA
```

Comment: Where does `timevis` come from? What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can arrange data on `name` and `date` to mark 1st and 2nd(end) record. Finally, join data having status `+` an `-` as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df_mod <- df %>% mutate(date = dmy(date)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(name, date) %>%
  mutate(discard = ifelse(row_number() == 1 & status=="-", TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  filter(!discard) %>%  #discard if 1st row is "-".
  group_by(name)  %>%
  mutate(RecNo = ceiling(row_number()/2)) %>%
  select(-discard)


df_mod %>%
  filter(status=="+") %>%
  left_join(filter(df_mod, status == "-"), by=c("name","RecNo")) %>%
  arrange(date.x) %>%
  select(date = date.x, status = status.x, name, enddate = date.y, -RecNo, -status.y)

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
# # Groups: name [3]
#   date       status name  enddate   
#   <date>     <chr>  <chr> <date>    
# 1 2001-01-01 +      A     2001-01-07
# 2 2001-01-02 +      B     2001-01-03
# 3 2001-01-02 +      C     2001-01-09
# 4 2001-01-04 +      B     2001-01-13
# 5 2001-01-11 +      A     NA
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"date     status name
01.01.2001  +   A
02.01.2001  +   B
02.01.2001  +   C
03.01.2001  -   B
04.01.2001  +   B
07.01.2001  -   A
09.01.2001  -   C
11.01.2001  +   A
13.01.2001  -   B",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works perfectly. Now I found that the very first records of some events is "-". These rows must be deleted for this code. How can I filter them out?

Comment: @zathura Updated the answer to discard 1st row if that is `-`.